# Телеграм бот не отрабатывает нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, button

Есть телеграм бот с какой то функциональностью (вполне исправной), захотели прикрутить кнопки для принятия или отклонения заказа. Кнопки появляются, НО не хотят никак работать. Пробовали переписывать, но каждый раз упираемся в одно и то же в чём же моя проблема?

```
def buttons():
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    accept_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_data='accept')
    reject_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отклонить', callback_data='reject')
    markup.row(accept_button, reject_button)
    return markup

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_button_click(callback):
    if callback.data == 'accept':
        print('Нажали кнопку')
        sheet.update_cell(last_row + counter, 5, 'п')  # обновляем значение в столбце E
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ успешно принят!')
    elif callback.data == 'reject':
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ отклонен.')


def check_all():
    global last_row
    global counter
    global chat_id
    if sheet.cell(last_row + counter, 6).value != sheet.cell(last_row + counter + 1, 6).value:
        message = 'Новый заказ! \n Адрес: ' + str(value(6)) + '\n Номер: ' + str(
            value(7)) + '\n Время заказа: ' + str(value(8)) + '\n Состав заказа: ' + str(
            value(10)) + '\n Палочки: ' + str(value(12)) + '\n Соевый соус: ' + str(
            value(13)) + '\n Имбирь: ' + str(value(14)) + '\n Васаби: ' + str(
            value(15)) + '\n Способ оплаты: ' + str(value(16)) + '\n Итоговая цена: ' + str(
            value(17))
        bot.send_message(chat_id, message, reply_markup=buttons())
        counter += 1
        print("Алло уеба заказ пришел")


def set_trigger():
    import time
    while True:
        check_all()
        time.sleep(60)


set_trigger()

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё таки пришлось использовать асинхронность, так что, если у кого то такая же проблема с циклами, то примерно вот:

```
def run_in_executor(func):
    """Run a blocking function in a separate thread."""

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        new_args = [arg for arg in args]
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *new_args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def value(row):
    global last_row
    global counter
    new_value = sheet.cell(last_row + counter, row).value
    return new_value


def buttons():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    accept_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_data='accept')
    reject_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отклонить', callback_data='reject')
    markup.row(accept_button, reject_button)
    return markup


async def check_all():
    global last_row
    global counter
    global chat_id
    if sheet.cell(last_row + counter, 6).value != sheet.cell(last_row + counter + 1, 6).value:
        message = 'Новый заказ! \n Адрес: ' + str(value(6)) + '\n Номер: ' + str(
            value(7)) + '\n Время заказа: ' + str(value(8)) + '\n Состав заказа: ' + str(
            value(10)) + '\n Палочки: ' + str(value(12)) + '\n Соевый соус: ' + str(
            value(13)) + '\n Имбирь: ' + str(value(14)) + '\n Васаби: ' + str(
            value(15)) + '\n Способ оплаты: ' + str(value(16)) + '\n Итоговая цена: ' + str(
            value(17))
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, message, reply_markup=buttons())
        counter += 1
        print("Алло уеба заказ пришел")


async def inf_loop():
    while True:
        await check_all()
        await asyncio.sleep(15)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def handle_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query.data == 'accept':
        print('Нажали кнопку')
        sheet.update_cell(last_row + counter - 1, 5, 'п')  # обновляем значение в столбце E
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ успешно принят!')
    elif callback_query.data == 'reject':
        # Delete the original message
        message_to_delete = callback_query.message
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message_to_delete.chat.id, message_id=message_to_delete.message_id)
        # Send a new message
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ отклонен.')


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    print("кто-то что-то написал")
    if message.text == 'Принять':
        sheet.update_cell(last_row + counter, 5, 'п')  # обновляем значение в столбце E
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ успешно принят!')
    elif message.text == 'Отклонить':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ отклонен.')


async def main():
    polling_task = asyncio.create_task(dp.start_polling())
    loop_task = asyncio.create_task(inf_loop())
    await asyncio.gather(polling_task, loop_task)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```